# Clickhouse WITH FILL STEP toIntervalHour(1) exception

Tags: clickhouse

I'm trying to do an aggregation using `ORDER by date WITH FILL STEP toIntervalHour(1)` but ClickHouse returns me an exception:

```
Received exception from server (version 23.5.3):
Code: 475. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: Value of step is to low (3600 seconds). Must be >= 1 day. (INVALID_WITH_FILL_EXPRESSION)
```

I couldn't find any related config in `config.xml` to tweak. How can I change this limit to allow hourly fill step?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's hard-coded. Here is the source code:

```
Int64 avg_seconds = get<Int64>(descr.fill_step) * descr.step_kind->toAvgSeconds();
if (std::abs(avg_seconds) < 86400)
     throw Exception(ErrorCodes::INVALID_WITH_FILL_EXPRESSION,
               "Value of step is to low ({} seconds). Must be >= 1 day", std::abs(avg_seconds));
```

Comment: That's an weird limitation I wasn't expecting to see in ClickHouse. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue was with my query:

```sql
SELECT
    toDate(created_at) AS date,
    count(*) AS total
FROM foo
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC WITH FILL STEP toIntervalHour(1)
```

Casting `toDate` and then ordering with fill step `toIntervalHour` was the issue. Here is a working example:

```sql
SELECT
    toDateTime(created_at) AS date,
    count(*) AS total
FROM foo
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC WITH FILL STEP toIntervalHour(1)
```